# Manually built OAuth login flow, which platform to specify in the Facebook App details

Tags: facebook, flutter, oauth

I want to provide the ability for my users to log-in to my app using OAuth providers like Google, Facebook, etc. For those purposes, I've built a unified OAuth login system that involves my server, based on instructions like this: [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). From my users' accounts, I need only default permissions plus e-mail, with those permissions I've publish my Facebook app, and review was not required.

Today I've received a message from Facebook where I was asked to specify my Facebook app platforms, and this is where the problems begin. All provided but Facebook platform templates are not quite suitable for me:

- currently, I'm using my system on the mobile app, but it is pointless to specify my package ID or provide some hashes because the app is not using Facebook SDK and those data will never be, received by Facebook
- also, it is not correct to give the Facebook just my website URL it doesn't use Facebook login buttons or so, for log-in process communicates only mobile app and back-end

So, here my question.
Which platform I need to specify in my Facebook App if I've used instruction [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) to build my log-in flow.
Any ideas? May be someone have experience with this?

P.S. my app built on Flutter.

Comment: That whole login flow _is_ website-based, so you will have to fill out the Website platform settings.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for your reply! For me, it is unclear what I need to provide for verification. If it must be just a working web site with name/domain matching to the Facebook app/OAuth URLs, it's ok. If I need to provide all the above, and my site must provide the ability to log-in with Facebook, there are problems. Because in my case, the login routine is the API calls.

Comment: _“Because in my case, the login routine is the API calls.”_ - you can not login by making API calls alone. The user must enter their credentials and accept the requested permissions somewhere - and with the non-native authentication flows, that happens on a website. (Either in a browser, or something like a webview component.) And Facebook demands that you have a publicly reachable privacy policy for apps that use web login flows as well, so make sure to fill that field, too.

Comment: @CBroe, maybe I was not accurate. I'm not saying that I don't have a website that represents my project. What I'm saying is that I don't provide nowhere on the site buttons like "Sign-up/in with Facebook". 
At the same time, all the data I can specify when adding site as a Facebook application's platform is a single link. And I've thought that resource beyond that link must demonstrate the understandable usage of the Facebook app's credentials. What is difficult in my case because log-in process must be initiated from the client app.

Comment: No, it doesn’t need to demonstrate anything - not for the functionality to work. (Now if you were talking about app review, where they somehow want to see what your app is doing, that would be a different thing - but that depends less on the settings, and more on the info you provide when you submit for review.) The Website URL for example determines where the JS SDK for this app would be able to initialize.